# Access x-editable dynamically generated form or input

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, x-editable

Upon clicking an element, x-editable creates an `input` element.  Within the validate callback, how can I access that element?  I "could" do so by assigning a unique class using `inputclass` to each time the plugin is applied to an element, however, this offers very little flexibility.  Within the call back, `this` references the original element, not the `input` element.

https://jsfiddle.net/cgym6m3v/1/

```
<p>Name</p><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="name"></a>

$('#name').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'Name',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    pk: 123,
    validate: function (value) {
        console.log(this,value);
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do? You can defer the text update if that's the idea

Comment: @charlietfl  Wrap a form around it and validate it using jQuery's validation plugin.  As a workaround, I am playing with just creating a new input and setting it's value to `value`.

Comment: But it already has a form wrapped around it. Why can't you just use the regex from validate plugin in the validate callback of editable?

Comment: @charlietfl  Could the validation plugin be used in the validate callback of editable?  Thank you

Comment: probably not simple. Both plugins would have there own submit event handlers.

Comment: Hasn't been too simple, but I think I am close.  Please see https://jsfiddle.net/hytzt39u/1/.  Problem is it always validates as true.

Comment: @charlietfl  If I can get a hold of either the form element or the input element created by x-editable, I can validate it.  Just can't seem to select it.  Any thoughts?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the cleanest solution, but it will work.  Maybe there isn't a clean solution at all...

```
$('.bla').editable({
    inputclass: function(e, f) {
        $("a[aria-describedby=" + $(this).closest(".ui-tooltip").prop("id") + "]").data("shared", this);
    },
    validate: function (value) {
        console.log("validate", $(this).data("shared"));
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cgym6m3v/5/